# In Processing - one soundFile throughout the whole animation but only one class object interact with the sound

Tags: java, class, audio, processing

I am still super new to Processing, and I am trying my best to figure out this project:(

I'm trying to create a sequenced animation with one soundFile playing throughout the whole animation. However, only **class Two** needs to have the sound responsive element.

All three class objects work fine individually in their own sketch file. But not when they are in one sketch as classes.

Right now I only have the sound file in class two since I don't know how to have the same sound file but responds to a different class.

I'm not sure how **background** works when different classes need it on and off.
I am also unsure if my way of sequencing is correct...
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you guys!

```
One objectone;
Two objecttwo;
Three objectthree;

int myAnimationCounter = 0; //set myAnimationCounter incerment to 0, so allows to reset to 0 to start the animation.
int myAnimationCounter1 = 0;
int myAnimationCounter2 = 0;//set a parallel myAnimationCounter incerment to 0.
boolean startAnimation = false;  //Boolean switch to control starting animation.
boolean openingAnimation = false;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight); //sketch present
  frameRate(50);
  objectone=new One();
  objecttwo=new Two();
  objectthree=new Three();
}

void draw() {
  
  if (openingAnimation) { //start the opening seq when press spacebar
    if ( myAnimationCounter>0 && myAnimationCounter<750) {
      objectone.show1();
    }
    myAnimationCounter++;
  }
  
  //when clicking the mouse 'openingAnimation' stops, playing 'startAnimation'
  
  if (startAnimation) {        
    if (myAnimationCounter1 > 0  && myAnimationCounter1 < 2500) {
        objecttwo.update2();
        objecttwo.show2();
      } else
      
        if (myAnimationCounter1 > 2500  && myAnimationCounter1 < 3000) {
objectthree.update3();                  
objectthree.show3();
        }
    myAnimationCounter1++;

//rect shape drawing at the bottom of the screen showing the playing progression of the animation

    if (myAnimationCounter2 > 0 && myAnimationCounter2 < 9000) { //independent animation through out the whole animation 
      fill(d);
      noStroke();
      rect(width, height-10, 10, width/myAnimationCounter2);
    }
    myAnimationCounter2++;
  }
}//end of draw


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    openingAnimation = true;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    startAnimation = true;
    openingAnimation=false;

    myAnimationCounter=0;
    myAnimationCounter1=0;
    myAnimationCounter2=0;
  }
```

```
class One {
  void show1() {
 background(bg);
}
}
```

```
class Two {
  import processing.sound.*;
  SoundFile loadSound; 
  Amplitude measureVol;
 void update2() {
    loadSound = new SoundFile(this, "music.mp3"); 
    loadSound.loop();  
    measureVol = new Amplitude(this);
    measureVol.input(loadSound);
  } 
  void show2() {
   float howLoud = measureVol.analyze();
}
}
```

```
class Three {
 void update3() {
  background(0);
}
 void show3() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your sound code in its own separate class. Then, have the class instantiated in `Setup` and injected into class `Two` as an argument. Make sure this class for delivering audio capabilities has public methods for the operations you wish to call from within `Two`.

For example:

```
class MyAudioClass {

SoundFile loadSound; 
Amplitude measureVol;

    public MyAudioClass() {
        measureVol = new Amplitude(this);
    }

    public void loadSound(String soundFileName) {
        loadSound = new SoundFile(this, soundFileName);
        measureVol = input(loadSound);
    }

    public void playSound() {
        loadSound.loop();
    }

    public float getHowLoud() {
        return measureVol.analyze();
    }
}
```

Then, in `Two`:

```
class Two {
    private MySoundClass mySoundClass;
  
    // using Constructor Dependency Injection
    public Two(MySoundClass mySoundClass) {
        this.mySoundClass = mySoundClass;        
    }

    public float showHowLoud() {
        return mySoundClass.getHowLoud();
    }
```

*(Caution: I haven't used Processing and I am just converting what you wrote based on best guesses--so there may be some tweaking needed.)*

IDK if you also need the class injected into `One` or `Three`. Maybe you only need to start it playing in `Setup`? As long as you are dealing with the same instance in `Setup` as you are in `Two` (or whatever other classes you inject into), things should be fine.

This pattern of coding is often referred to as *Dependency Injection* or as an example of *Inversion of Control* and is pretty useful. A variant would be to use a setter method instead of the constructor for delivering your sound-resource class.

> Inversion of control —the concept behind DI
>
> This states that a class should not configure its dependencies statically
> but should be configured by some other class from outside.
>
> It is the fifth principle of S.O.L.I.D — the five basic principles of
> object-oriented programming and design by Uncle Bob — which states
> that a class should depend on abstraction and not upon concretions (in
> simple terms, hard-coded).
>
> According to the principles, a class should concentrate on fulfilling
> its responsibilities and not on creating objects that it requires to
> fulfill those responsibilities. And that’s where dependency injection
> comes into play: it provides the class with the required objects.

The above is excerpted from the article [A Quick Intro to Dependency Injection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/).

Answer (score 0):

From your code this is the sequencing I understand:

- if space was pressed and instance of `One` will display for the first 750 "ticks" (15s at 50fps)
- if mouse is pressed all counters reset as well as flags
- an instance of `Two` update and display for the first
  2500 "ticks"(50s at 50fps)
- then an instance of `Three` will update
  and display between 2500 and 3000 "ticks" (50s to 60s at 50fps)
- in parallel, for the first 9000 "ticks" (180s at 50fps) a shrinking rectangle will be displayed

Regarding `background()`: it simply clears what's been previously drawn, otherwise drawn content accumulates.

Take this basic example:

```
void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  background(255);
}

void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  background(255);
}
```

As you drag the mouse on screen lines keeps being drawn (even on top of each other). When a key is pressed the background (set to white) is redrawn on top of all the previous lines, clearing them.

This brings to another minor point in your code:

```
void mousePressed() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    startAnimation = true;
    openingAnimation=false;

    myAnimationCounter=0;
    myAnimationCounter1=0;
    myAnimationCounter2=0;
  }
}
```

The [`mousePressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html) function only gets called when the mouse is pressed which makes the if condition checking if the mouse is pressed redundant. This should suffice:

```
void mousePressed() {
  startAnimation = true;
  openingAnimation=false;

  myAnimationCounter=0;
  myAnimationCounter1=0;
  myAnimationCounter2=0;
}
```

Regarding the background sound, it seems to be loaded multiple times per second in `update2()`:

```
class Two {
  import processing.sound.*;
  SoundFile loadSound; 
  Amplitude measureVol;
 void update2() {
    loadSound = new SoundFile(this, "music.mp3"); 
    loadSound.loop();  
    measureVol = new Amplitude(this);
    measureVol.input(loadSound);
  } 
  void show2() {
   float howLoud = measureVol.analyze();
}
}
```

My assumption is `update()` would be called multiple times to update numbers while `show()` would be called multiple times to render those values (as text, shapes, etc.)

Since you instantiate `Two` in `setup()` you could load the sound once in `Two`'s constructor:

```
class Two {

  SoundFile loadSound; 
  Amplitude measureVol;

  float howLoud;
  // this gets called once when you make a new instance (e.g = new Two())
  Two() {
    loadSound = new SoundFile(this, "music.mp3"); 
    loadSound.loop();  
    measureVol = new Amplitude(this);
    measureVol.input(loadSound);
  }

  void update() {
    howLoud = measureVol.analyze();
  } 
  void show() {
    fill(127);
    text("Two instance show() -> howLoud: " + howLoud, 10, 15);
  }
}
```

This way the sound is created and looped once, then only analysed when `update()`  is called (within the first 2500 updates of `startAnimation`)

To keep things consistent I recommend using `update()`/`show()` and ideally name the instance similar to the other variables (e.g. `objectOne`, `objectTwo`, `objectThree`). Ideally import statements would be at the top of the code.

Here's a slightly tweaked version of your code with the above remarks in mind:

```
import processing.sound.*;

One objectOne;
Two objectTwo;
Three objectThree;

int myAnimationCounter = 0; //set myAnimationCounter incerment to 0, so allows to reset to 0 to start the animation.
int myAnimationCounter1 = 0;
int myAnimationCounter2 = 0;//set a parallel myAnimationCounter incerment to 0.
boolean startAnimation = false;  //Boolean switch to control starting animation.
boolean openingAnimation = false;

color bg = color(255);
color d = color(192, 0, 0);

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight); //sketch present
  frameRate(50);

  objectOne   = new One();
  objectTwo   = new Two();
  objectThree = new Three();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  if (openingAnimation) { //start the opening seq when press spacebar
    if ( myAnimationCounter>0 && myAnimationCounter<750) {
      objectOne.show();
    }
    myAnimationCounter++;
  }

  //when clicking the mouse 'openingAnimation' stops, playing 'startAnimation'

  if (startAnimation) {        
    if (myAnimationCounter1 > 0  && myAnimationCounter1 < 2500) {
      objectTwo.update();
      objectTwo.show();
    } else if (myAnimationCounter1 > 2500  && myAnimationCounter1 < 3000) {
      objectThree.update();                  
      objectThree.show();
    }
    myAnimationCounter1++;

    //rect shape drawing at the bottom of the screen showing the playing progression of the animation

    if (myAnimationCounter2 > 0 && myAnimationCounter2 < 9000) { //independent animation through out the whole animation
      fill(d);
      noStroke();
      rect(mouseX, mouseY, 10, width / myAnimationCounter2);
    }
    myAnimationCounter2++;
  }

  // debug
  fill(127);
  text("openingAnimation: " + openingAnimation + "\n" + 
    "startAnimation: " + startAnimation + "\n" + 
    "myAnimationCounter: " + myAnimationCounter + "\n" +
    "myAnimationCounter1: " + myAnimationCounter1 + "\n" + 
    "myAnimationCounter2: " + myAnimationCounter2 + "\n", 10, 30);
}//end of draw


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    openingAnimation = true;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  startAnimation = true;
  openingAnimation=false;

  myAnimationCounter=0;
  myAnimationCounter1=0;
  myAnimationCounter2=0;
}

class One {
  void show() {
    background(bg);
    text("One instance show()", 10, 15);
  }
}

class Two {

  SoundFile loadSound; 
  Amplitude measureVol;

  float howLoud;

  Two() {
    loadSound = new SoundFile(this, "music.mp3"); 
    loadSound.loop();  
    measureVol = new Amplitude(this);
    measureVol.input(loadSound);
  }

  void update() {
    howLoud = measureVol.analyze();
  } 
  void show() {
    fill(127);
    text("Two instance show() -> howLoud: " + howLoud, 10, 15);
  }
}

class Three {

  void update() {
  }
  void show() {
    background(0);
    text("Three instance show()", 10, 15);
  }
}
```

Additionally there are a few other minor changes I've made:

- I've added `text()` at the bottom of `draw()` so it's easier to debug the behaviour. You can visualise values of boolean values as well as counters.
- each `show()` method also uses `text()` to visualise which instance is rendering
- it was unclear what the purpose of the `rect()` call was, however the coordinates were offscreen. As a test I've snapped the `rect()` position to the mouse position: feel free to change that to something that makes sense for your application. If it's a visualisation of the animation duration, the assumption is the total duration is 9000 counts. Still it's unclear wether the intention was to render this as a horizontal or vertical bar (perhaps vertical?) and if it should grow or shrink (currently it shrinks)

I'm also noticing `myAnimationCounter2` updates at the same time/rate as `myAnimationCounter1` which makes them identical. If this is the case, `myAnimationCounter1` could be used draw the rectangle as well and `myAnimationCounter2` could be discarded to simplify the code. If you do have plans to have `myAnimationCounter1` update independently from `myAnimationCounter2` in the future then it's worth keeping it around.

The counters will reset every time the user clicks, however the opening animation only gets displayed once after the user presses the spacebar but it can not be reset.